# Pull rebase from remote branch is different of git fetch + rebase

Tags: git

I have a problem. When I do this command

```
git pull --rebase origin dev
```

my local branch derives from my remote branch. When I do  `git log HEAD..origin/dev` , Git displays some commits.

But (after a `git reset --hard origin/dev`) when i do

```
git fetch origin dev
git rebase origin/dev
```

There si no derivation. No return for  `git log HEAD..origin/dev`

Why and how can I do a  `git pull --rebase origin dev` without derivation.

Answer (score 1):

When you did your `git reset --hard origin/dev`, you changed your current branch (which I am assuming is `dev`) to point to `origin/dev`. `git fetch origin dev` was probably a no-op, as you were already up to date due to your `git pull` earlier. So when you did `git rebase origin/dev`, nothing happened, as `dev` already pointed to `origin/dev`.

Had you done the fetch and rebase first instead of doing a pull, you would have seen the same list of commits as when you did the pull.